# Scala, animations and graphical user interface

Tags: user-interface, graphics, scala

I want to be able to do graphics with Scala programming language.
Need to be able to do animations and attractive user interface, where to start?

Answer (score 5):

Remember that scala can use java classes? :) I would start by learning the [Swing framework](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/), which is a Java framework containing everything you need to get you started building GUIs. For animations, have a look at `javax.swing.Timer`, which fires events on the event dispatch thread (the thread on which all Swing GUIs must run on - Swing is *not* thread safe).

Scala provides helper classes simplifying the building of swing applications in the package `scala.swing`, its API found at [**scala swing API 2.7.5**](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/swing%24content.html)

Java also provides an experimental framework to simplify Swing development, the [appframework](https://appframework.dev.java.net/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Note that appframework is dead, and has been replaced by [BSAF](http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/pages/Home)

Answer (score 1):

As Flaviu said, anything that's available in Java is also available in Scala for creating nice GUIs.

If you want to learn how to write really nice and sexy GUIs with Swing, I recommend the book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) by Chet Haase and Romain Guy.